# iPhone website wont scroll - height 100% issue?

Tags: css

I have a website and it wont scroll on iPhone, when i open up web developers toolbar and highlight the HTML tag, BOOM! it starts to scroll, buyt I exit the developers tools and it wont scroll, can anyone provide any insight?

Heres my viewport tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

this is my site if you wanna take a look: http://nyeto.com

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? You've got it set to height 100% and overflow-y:hidden. It's not going to scroll?

Comment: sorry forgot to say, I am using media queries to target iphone, here is my html `html, body {overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:scroll; height:auto;}`

Answer (score 0):

While you've implemented the media queries OK (it works in Chrome's [device metrics](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) overrides, even at 320x480) but not on the device. What's strange, is that on the iOS device, you can scroll if you swipe on the black header bar. This says to me that you've got some 'ontouch' event overriding scroll.

To troubleshoot further: Follow [these instructions](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/) to debug Mobile Safari.

You'll also note that you have several errors in the console, you may want to fix those.